# Gitlab pipeline job fails to execute dependency job on branch push but works for master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, gatling

I have below my CI configurations for my pipeline. All works fine when I push on the master branch. But the pipeline fails to execute job dependencies when I push on another branch other than master.

What am I be missing?

```
stages:
  - prep
  - tests

create-users-file:
  stage: prep
  script:
    - ./create_users.sh
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src/test/resources/data/user.csv
    expire_in: 7 days

AccountSimulation:
  stage: tests
  dependencies:
    - create-user-file
  script:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" ./mvnw clean gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=dev.pallet.gatling.simulations.AccountSimulation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./target/gatling/*
    expire_in: 30 days

AnalysisSimulation:
  stage: tests
  dependencies:
    - create-user-file
  script:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m" ./mvnw clean gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=dev.pallet.gatling.simulations.AnalysisSimulation
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./target/gatling/*
    expire_in: 30 days
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the issue was.

The env variables were marked as protected. This meant that the variables were only available to protected branches, and not all branches.
unchecking the protected variables and masking them to avoid leaking secrets in pipeline logs resolved the issue.